# React JS Conditional Rendering like Eval

Tags: reactjs

I have a dynamic button being created. The problem is that the `CurrentPage` and the `KeyIndex` are already evaluated prior to rendering.

```
private DisplayButtons = () => {
  let cont = [];
  let startAt, endAt;
  startAt = this.state.StartAt;
  endAt = this.state.EndAt;
  if (this.state.CurrentPage == 1) {
    endAt = endAt =
      this.state.TotalRecord / this.state.PageSize >= 5
        ? 5
        : Math.ceil(this.state.TotalRecord / this.state.PageSize);
  }
  for (var i = startAt; i <= endAt; i++) {
    cont.push(
      <li onClick={this.onPagerClick} data-id={i} className="sui-pager-element">
        <a
          className={
            this.state.CurrentPage == this.state.KeyIndex
              ? 'sui-selected sui-pager-element'
              : 'sui-pager-element'
          }
        >
          {i}
        </a>
      </li>,
    );
  }

  this.setState({
    DataButtons: cont,
  });
};
```

Comment: Hello @ping pong, could you be more specific? Which is the problem and your expected result. There is an error logged in the console?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand this isolated code. However, I make some comments that I hope will improve its functioning.

1. I understand that `DisplayButtons` is an internal function of a class component. If that is the case, it should be called `displayButtons` with first lower case.
2. You can refactor like this:

```
    const { startAt, CurrentPage, TotalRecord, PageSize, KeyIndex } = this.state;`
    let { endAt } = this.state;
```

3. Better use FP in the for loop. It is not very clear.
4. `cont` should be an array of objects instead of html. Then, in the render, you do something like this:  `{ DataButtons.map(b => <ButtonView>) }`.